# Where are my SSH keys used for authentication being stored on Mac OS X if not in .ssh?

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm trying to set up ssh to work with git on Mac OS X, and I can't find my keys. I tried generating new keys, using existing keys, copying exactly the same ~/.ssh directory used by git on my Windows machine, and nothing made any difference on the Mac.

I've had an ssh key I've used for some time to access my server from the Mac, which I thought was the id_rsa/id_rsa.pub pair in ~/,ssh. When I moved the ~/.ssh directory out of the way to check my assumption that this was where ssh was getting the keys and then tried ssh (from Terminal) to my server, it didn't recognize the host, as I expected since known_hosts was moved, but I *still* got in to the server *without a password*.

So it must still be using a secret key corresponding to one of the authorized public keys on the server, not just a session key, so it's not the scenario [here](https://superuser.com/questions/370028/where-are-my-private-public-ssh-keys-on-unix), but where is it getting it if not from ~/.ssh?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

- Any chance you once did something like `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to add your SSH private key to your OS X Keychain? For several years now (since about Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard), the `ssh` client in OS X knows how to retrieve SSH keys from the Keychain. Use `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app` to search your Keychain for anything with "ssh" in the name.
- Any chance you set up the third-party [SSHKeychain](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/) app (icon looks like a puffer fish) to do this for you pre-Leopard, and you're still running it today?
- Any chance you've forgotten that you once set up `ssh-agent(1)`, and maybe your shell startup scripts on your Mac are starting the agent and doing `ssh-add(1)` for your keys that exist in a different location?
- Any chance you've edited `/etc/ssh_config` to add extra `IdentityFile` entries to look for keys in another location?
- Any chance...umm...your account on the remote machine doesn't require a password?

Comment: Yes, it was in the keychain. Thanks for telling me that ssh is special on (Snow) Leopard.